# How do I configure the duration of the checksum links?

Tags: civimail, tokens

Is there a way to configure the duration of the checksum links used when sending a mail - either globally or using a specific parameter in the token ?

I can't find any documentation on this but i'm pretty sure it's doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting you're looking for is here: **Administer menu > System Settings > Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.)**

The second option is "checksum lifespan".

Comment: Ah... right. I should have thought of this admin page for everything that doesn't fit anywhere :)  Thanks !